# example of dynamic nature of javaScript

Tags: javascript, dynamic, static-analysis

I read this answer about the dynamic nature of JavaScript. But I did not understand it properly.

> Most languages have some aspect of dynamic behavior. Even statically typed languages can have a dynamic or variant data type that can contain different data types.
> JavaScript is called a dynamic language because it doesn't just have a few dynamic aspects, pretty much everything is dynamic.
> All variables are dynamic (both in type and existence), and even the code is dynamic. You can create new variables at runtime, and the type of variables is determined at runtime. You can create new functions at any time, or replace existing functions. When used in a browser, code is added when more script files are loaded, and you can load more files any time you like.
> Nowadays JavaScript is compiled in many implementations, and static code and static types are generated in the background. However, the behavior is still dynamic, the compiler only generates static types when it finds that the dynamic aspects are not used for a specific object.

Can you give me an example that shows me the dynamic nature of JavaScript and the generation of functions and variables, etc. at runtime? An example on which static analysis is difficult.

Comment: `var x = 4; x = "Now it's a string"`

Comment: Thanks, dynamic change of type is easy for static analysis. I meant generating code and variables at runtime.

Comment: `eval` can be used to do both. You can also construct `script` elements and their content dynamically. Because of this, dynamically generating code/variables is mainly a matter of string manipulation.